Существуют ли правила объясняющие, нужно ли создавать новую функцию в классе?(Python)
Имеется код, создающий класс Bank, который работает с объектами класса Account. В данном случае, представлены методы инициализации и создания нового аккаунта(new_account). Есть два способа реализации данной задачи, которые отличаются лишь наличием метода create_account во втором варианте программы. Метод create_account вызывается ТОЛЬКО в методе new_account, больше он нигде не применяется, даже вне класса. Какая реализация лучше? Или любая из них считается нормальной практикой? Какой смысл использовать отдельный метод во второй реализации, если мы его используем лишь один раз в new_account?
class Bank:
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts_dict = {}
        self.next_account_number = 0

    def new_account(self):
        user_name = input('Name: ')
        user_password = input('Password: ')
        user_balance = input('Balance: ')

        new_account = Account(user_name, user_password, user_balance)
        new_account_number = self.next_account_number
        self.accounts_dict[new_account_number] = new_account
        self.next_account_number += 1

        print(f'\nYou account number: {new_account_number}\n')

class Bank:
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts_dict = {}
        self.next_account_number = 0

    def create_account(self, user_name, user_password, user_balance):
        new_account = Account(user_name, user_password, user_balance)
        new_account_number = self.next_account_number
        self.accounts_dict[new_account_number] = new_account
        self.next_account_number += 1
        return new_account_number

    def new_account(self):
        user_name = input('Name: ')
        user_password = input('Password: ')
        user_balance = input('Balance: ')

        print(f'\nYou account number: {new_account_number}\n')


Нормально дробить на функции, если функция начинает выполнять больше одной "неделимой" задачи. В данном случае второй вариант в целом лучше, потому что вам может внезапно понадобиться создавать аккаунт не по вводу из консоли, а например у вас приложение становится графическим, и ввод через input становится неактуальным. Ввод вообще стоит вынести из этого класса.

@insolor Хорошо! Спасибо за совет
